# mysql pick particular string only

Tags: mysql

I have a column in database  and having value like this

```
course_repeatfkfjkjfjkfer_10_topics_0_presentation_link
course_repeatfkfjfkfkfklfflkflkfs_1_presentation_link
course_repeatfkfjfkfkfklfflkflkfs_2_presentation_link
coursek_epeatfkfjfkfkfklfflkflkfs_10_presentation_link
course_hdhdhhdhdjhdrepeatfkfjfkfkfklfflkflkfs_21_presentation_link
```

and so on.

I need to pick 0,1,2,10,21, number before **_presentation_link** , But i need this in mysql as well

i used substr in mysql, but that is not working. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a combination of `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and `REPLACE()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(col, '_presentation_link', ''), '_', -1)
FROM yourTable
```

Taking `course_repeatfkfjkjfjkfer_10_topics_0_presentation_link` as an example, after the replacement, this would become:

```
course_repeatfkfjkjfjkfer_10_topics_0
```

The call to `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` then grabs everything appearing *after* the final underscore, which is the number you want to capture.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index` twice like this:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, '_', -3), '_', 1)
from t
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/NFPLZM26468)